# Private variables vs Public variables and overwriting a function with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really new to python and OOP, and just trying to get the hang of things. But this I'm not really understanding. I have this simple class, but when I run this I get *'Person' object has no attribute 'first'*. So I read here  that this is because of the ._ (private variables). Can I somehow access them? If I then remove the ._ and have public classes (I guess) I get this *'str' object is not callable*. So if I understand it right, I'm overwriting a function with a string, is that happening where I declare p1 and p2? How can I get around that?

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self._first = kwargs['first']
      self._last = kwargs['last']
      self._age = kwargs['age']

      def first(self):
          return self._first

      def last(self):
          return self._last

      def age(self):
          return self._age

def printPerson(o):
   print('The persons name is {0} {1} and the age is 
   {2}.'.format(o.first(), o.last(), o.age()))

def main():
    p1 = Person(first='John', last='Stevenson', age=35)
    p2 = Person(first='Ash', last='Bradley', age=35)
    printPerson(p1)
    printPerson(p2)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: There is nothing private in Python. Leading `_` is only a convention to warn you that the author wants it to be private, but you can access it like any other. Double underscores will invoke "name mangling" but you can get round that too.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. And your print statement won't work either the way it is formatted. If you fix that it'll work just fine,.

Comment: The issue here is indentation, the methods need to be indented at the level of the class, not inside the `__init__` function. That just creates a bunch of local functions that get discarded with `__init__` terminates. Note, in Python, generally you would use a property for your `first`, `last`, and `age` methods. Or rather, in this case, you would just make those normal attributes and not use the `_first` single-underscore versions to begin with at all

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I remove the _ then I get 'str' object is not callable error. Do I need to change the function names or the variable names to over come that error?

Comment: @user3403590 I meant *just don't use functions at all*. Just use normal attributes. That would be the Pythonic way, unless you want to disallow *setting*, in which case, use a `property`. What is happening, btw, that causes that error is that you are setting an *instance variable* to the same name as the *class variable*, i.e., the method. So it shadows it, returns that value, which is a string, but you try to call it like a function, which fails with the error.

Comment: Basically, in Python, don't write getters and setters. Just use normal attributes

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self._first = dictionary['first']
        self._last = dictionary['last']
        self._age = dictionary['age']

    def first(self):
        return self._first

    def last(self):
        return self._last

    def age(self):
        return self._age

def printPerson(o):
   print('The persons name is {0} {1} and the age is {2}.'.format(o.first(), o.last(), o.age()))

def main():
    p1 = Person({'first': 'John', 'last': 'Stevenson', 'age': 35})
    p2 = Person({'first': 'Ash', 'last': 'Bradley', 'age': 35})
    printPerson(p1)
    printPerson(p2)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

this first of all fixes the indentation problem you had on the first, last, and age methods of your class. This may not be the exact solution you are looking for, but I implemented a dictionary that gets passed to the class when creating a new instance of it, in order to keep your same style of code using the keys `['first']`, `['last']`, and `['age']`. Also, you don't really need the first, last, or age methods in the class... Something like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self._first = dictionary['first']
        self._last = dictionary['last']
        self._age = dictionary['age']

    def printPerson(self):
        print('The persons name is {0} {1} and the age is {2}.'.format(self._first, self._last, self._age))

def main():
    p1 = Person({'first': 'John', 'last': 'Stevenson', 'age': 35})
    p2 = Person({'first': 'Ash', 'last': 'Bradley', 'age': 35})
    p1.printPerson()
    p2.printPerson()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

would work just as well, and in my opinion is a lot more clear what you are trying to accomplish. You could also define the arguments needed for the class as being part of it, and use defaults in case

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last='Doe', age=10):
        self._first = first
        self._last = last
        self._age = age

    def printPerson(self):
        print('The persons name is {0} {1} and the age is {2}.'.format(self._first, self._last, self._age))

def main():
    p1 = Person('John', 'Stevenson', 35)
    p2 = Person('Ash', last='Bradley', age=35)
    p1.printPerson()
    p2.printPerson()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

using this method you can see that the last name defaults to 'Doe', and the age defaults to 10. As shown you can specify these arguments from a syntax like you had `last='Bradley'`, or just omit the `last=` and Python will determine where they go based on the order they are given to the class when initializing an instance

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to simply comment this, but what @Reedinationer's answer is trying to say is that your indenting for first, last and age make them be a defined inside the __init__ method. As suggested fixing the indentation should fix that !

Comment: You really need to explain why your answer will resolve the issue that the question poses. Just giving a code answer without explanation isn't enough. Remember, this answer may well be viewed for years and therefore you should explain the issue and the resolution.

Comment: @Rolf Ok I added a better description, and an example of how I would improve it

Comment: "but I implemented a dictionary that gets passed to the class when creating a new instance of it." But *why*? Why not normal arguments? Why creates a completely useless dictionary that only get's passed in? And clearly, the OP wants to expose the `_first`, `_last` and `_age` attributes, so why the single underscore?